# Google maps - Status Codes - GeocoderStatus

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

Im having troubles with the geocoderStatus, basically I always got "google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK"
when I send a request even if the address is invalid or zero results,

This is my code

```
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
        var lon = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        searchStores(lat, lon);
    } else {
        $addressErrorP.removeClass('hide');
    }
```

For example:
If I send this address "1525 COLD SPRINGS RD, CA" I get this:

> latitude=38.746431&longitude=-120.86995890000003, which is ok

And if I send this as an address "#$^%#$^%#%#%#%#$%" I get this:

> 33.778175&longitude=76.57617140000002 which is nowhere
>   https://www.google.co.cr/maps/place/33%C2%B046'41.4%22N+76%C2%B034'34.2%22W/@33.778175,-76.5761714,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0?hl=en

So what I need to know when there is zero results to show an error message and not reload the page with the nowhere location , but I never get other thing that status OK

This is the documentation in https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding:

Status Codes

The status code may return one of the following values:

google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK indicates that the geocode was successful.
google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS indicates that the geocode was successful but returned no results. This may occur if the geocode was passed a non-existent address or a latng in a remote location.
google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT indicates that you are over your quota. Refer to the Usage limits exceeded article in the Google Maps API for Work documentation, which also applies to non-Business users, for more information.
google.maps.GeocoderStatus.REQUEST_DENIED indicates that your request was denied for some reason.
google.maps.GeocoderStatus.INVALID_REQUEST generally indicates that the query (address or latLng) is missing.

Comment: How are you calling the geocoder?  I get ZERO_RESULTS for `#$^%#$^%#%#%#%#$%`.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows an example where you get "OK" when you enter a garbage address and you believe you should get a different status.

Comment: Ohhh that is interesting: if I run this code  test.geocode( { 'address': "$%^$%^$^%"}, function(results, status) {console.log(status);
}); in the console I get zero results, but in my JS it does not work, I will trooubleshoot my code to see what is wrong

Comment: Well this is really weird, im testing this in the console and Im geting ok as a result:         test.geocode( {
            'address': "$%$%$%$%$%$%$%$%",
            'region': 'usa',
            'componentRestrictions':{
                'country':'US'
            }
        },
        function(results, status) {
            console.log("address: ", status);
            
        });

Comment: it seems that the 'componentRestrictions':{
                'country':'US'
            } is breaking up my code, does anyone know what I can restrict the search to a USA only ?